# if problem showing some syntax error

Tags: command

```
#!bin/bash

echo Where?
read Where

echo What?
read What

echo Number?
read Number

for inc in ’seq 1 1 $Number’ do

if [ $Where = Screen ] then
echo $What
fi

if [ $Where = File ] then   
echo $What > test1,txt
fi
done
```

when i run it,type Screen,then Marko,then type number 5 it shows me this error
It shows me sytax error near unexpected token if
'if [ $Where = Screen ] then'

Comment: Those don’t look like the backticks you want, around the `seq` call.

Comment: You are also missing a `/` in you first line.  It should read `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Also "then" is a command in bash, you have to put a `;` before that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` statement is missing a semicolon.  You want:

```
for inc in $( seq 1 1 "$Number" ); do
```

Comment: Well, there are (at least) two problems: the missing semicolon, and the fact that the code uses apostrophes to do command substitution.  (Also the lack of quoting, and the lank of proper indentation, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Start by running your code through https://www.shellcheck.net/